# sql missing comma

Tags: c#, sql, .net, oracle

```
protected void ImageButton2_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    string loginID = (String)Session["UserID"];
    string ID = txtID.Text;
    string password = txtPassword.Text;
    string name = txtName.Text;
    string position = txtPosition.Text;
    int status = 1;
    string createOn = validate.GetTimestamp(DateTime.Now); ;
    string accessRight;

    if (RadioButton1.Checked)
        accessRight = "Administrator";
    else
        accessRight = "Non-administrator";

    if (txtID.Text != "")
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "yourMessage", "alert('" + ID + "ha " + password + "ha " + status + "ha " + accessRight + "ha " + position + "ha " + name + "ha " + createOn + "');", true);

    string sqlcommand = "INSERT INTO USERMASTER (USERID,USERPWD,USERNAME,USERPOISITION,USERACCESSRIGHTS,USERSTATUS,CREATEDATE,CREATEUSERID) VALUES ("+ ID + "," + password + "," + name + "," + position + "," + accessRight + "," + status + "," + createOn + "," +loginID+ ")";
    readdata.updateData(sqlcommand);
}
```

I am passing the sqlcommand to readdata class for execute..and its throw me this error..

> ORA-00917: missing comma
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: ORA-00917:
>   missing comma.

The readdata class function code as below.

```
public void updateData(string SqlCommand)
{
    string strConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SOConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strConString);
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SqlCommand, conn);
    OleDbDataAdapter daPerson = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: check your data... might be some special characters? like a `'` or a `,`?

Comment: As @SaagarEliasJacky mentioned, your data input probably has a comma. Instead of concatenating string, try using [parameterized queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: is it because the datatype in datebase of "CREATEDATE" is timestramp and I declar the createon as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that most of your columns are variable-length character, they must be enclosed in single quotes.
So, instead of:

```
string sqlcommand = "INSERT INTO myTable (ColumnName) VALUES (" + InputValue + ")";
```

You would, at minimum, need this:

```
string sqlcommand = "INSERT INTO myTable (ColumnName) VALUES ('" + InputValue + "')";
```

The result of the first statement, for an InputValue of "foo", would be:

> INSERT INTO myTable (ColumnName) VALUES (foo)

which would result in a syntax error.

The second statement would be formatted correctly, as:

> INSERT INTO myTable (ColumnName) VALUES ('foo')

Additionally, this code seems to be using values entered directly by the user, into txtID, txtPassword, and so on. This is a SQL Injection attack vector. Your input needs to be escaped. Ideally, you should use parameterized queries here.

This appears to be c#. Please update your tags accordingly.
At any rate, if it is .Net, here is some more information about parameterizing your queries:

[OleDbCommand.Parameters Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[OleDbParameter Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: may I have a question regarding the TIMESTAMP in oracle what would be the format for it?

Comment: The most reliable way is to convert character strings to TIMESTAMP via TO_TIMESTAMP(). There are myriad format strings to use for your cases. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2118.htm#OLADM696

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string sqlcommand = "INSERT INTO USERMASTER (USERID,USERPWD,USERNAME,USERPOISITION,USERACCESSRIGHTS,USERSTATUS,CREATEDATE,CREATEUSERID) VALUES ('"+ ID + "','" + password + "','" + name + "','" + position + "','" + accessRight + "','" + status + "','" + createOn + "','" +loginID+ "')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenating the query and executing it is not reccomended as it may cause strong SQl Injection. Suppose if any one of those parameters contain a comma(,) like `USERPWD=passwo',rd` then query will devide it as `passwo` and `rd` by the comma. This may be a problem

It is recommended that you use "[Parameterized queries to prevent SQL Injection Attacks in SQL Server](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-Parameterized-queries-to-prevent-SQL-Injection-Attacks-in-SQL-Server.aspx)" and hope it will resolve your issue.

Your code can be rewritten as follows

```
protected void ImageButton2_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    string loginID = (String)Session["UserID"];
    string ID = txtID.Text;
    string password = txtPassword.Text;
    string name = txtName.Text;
    string position = txtPosition.Text;
    int status = 1;
    string createOn = validate.GetTimestamp(DateTime.Now); ;
    string accessRight;

    if (RadioButton1.Checked)
        accessRight = "Administrator";
    else
        accessRight = "Non-administrator";

    if (txtID.Text != "")
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "yourMessage", "alert('" + ID + "ha " + password + "ha " + status + "ha " + accessRight + "ha " + position + "ha " + name + "ha " + createOn + "');", true);

    string strQuery;
    OleDbCommand  cmd;
    strQuery = "INSERT INTO USERMASTER(USERID,USERPWD,USERNAME,USERPOISITION,USERACCESSRIGHTS,USERSTATUS,CREATEDATE,CREATEUSERID) VALUES(@ID,@password,@name,@position,@accessRight,@status,@createOn,@loginID)";

    cmd = new OleDbCommand(strQuery);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@position", position);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accessRight", accessRight);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", status);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@createOn", createOn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@loginID", loginID);

    bool isInserted =  readdata.updateData(cmd);
}
```

rewrite your updateData data as follows

```
private Boolean updateData(OleDbCommand cmd)
{
    string strConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SOConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strConString);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
    }
}
```